Access denied to signed AWS-URL after uploading to S3 Bucket
I am implementing one commonly used backend for our two front-end-applications in AWS.
In one of the frontend-applications I am storing in GraphQL and S3 Buckets.
GraphQL works good and stores successfully.
The S3-Bucket-Functionality also seems to work good - when I upload a picture, I get back a signed aws-url that I before was able to display, f.e. as an IMG-Element when backend and frontend were one and the same.
Now that I am pulling a different backend over it, I am getting this...
This is how the element looks like after uploading to S3:

So I can see I am getting back a URL from the Bucket. I understand, the file is saved there now, but i do not know. When I want to display the image or open the AWS-URL that leads to it, I am getting this error here:

Before seperating backend and frontend, this worked perfectly. Now with backend and frontend being seperate, I am getting this 403 (Forbidden) error now.
It comes back like this:
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>P3C4S7WX6FFD94P7</RequestId>
<HostId>J5nYRJtVeoWdpFxzAtj9JGNQ/9MVv7RdCw6jCX6WisMpRhfvBkPzm/7ZPWvWnh0YT0JUslJ7eQg=</HostId>
</Error>

When I am now looking into this Bucket via AWS-Console-Login, I can see that there is no file in it. Why do I get back this totally legit looking signed AWS-URL, when actually nothing is stored at all? Or is it stored and I cant see it?
So happy about any help! Thank you!
Before, this has worked perfectly, the files were stored in a folder called public, using the same appid as frontend and backend.
Now I am using a different backend, via amplify pull - and I am getting this behaviour.

A pre-signed URL is simply an authorisation given from a particular Access Key to access an object with a particular name. It is possible to create a pre-signed URL even for objects that don't exist, and in buckets that don't exist! It's even possible to create a pre-signed URL for an object in somebody else's bucket, but if the Access Key used to generate the URL does not have permission to access the object, then the pre-signed URL won't work. Think of it like a signature on a cheque, but if the account doesn't have money you won't get anything from the bank.
